# How to make sidebar and sections with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, web, layout

I'm trying to make a layout like this:
[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  background: gray;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
}

.sidebar{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.navbar{
    grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;

}
.section2{
    grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: white;
  height: 300px;

}
.section4{
    grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
}

.section3{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
    align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.section5{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="navbar">navbar</div>
  <div class="section2">section2</div>  
  <div class="section3">section3</div>
  <div class="section4">section4</div>
  <div class="section5">section5</div>
</div>
```

The output is shown here:

[image]

I highlighted in red some big problems, I have these massive gaps in between sections, and my columns aren't being centered in the grid I tried adding "justify-content: center" and "align-items: center" but none of those centered the sidebar sections and I have no clue how to reduce the gap in between the sections. How can I fix my code so it looks more like the layout in my mockup?

Comment: not possible with a css-grid as it works in a table like layout. You might achieve that with flexbox or you need to make a template grid that divides the page into 2 independent columns and place the divs/section manually into the columns.

Comment: @tacoshy wait the layout I have is not possible with CSS grid? dang thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated because with CSS Grid you have a grid...

[image: CSS GRID]

For your layout you must divide them on two sections like this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="left">
        <aside class="sidebar">sidebar</aside>
        <section class="section2">section2</section>
        <section class="section4">section4</section>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
        <nav class="navbar">navbar</nav>
        <section class="section3">section3</section>
        <section class="section5">section5</section>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tasmim-concept/pen/mdrxLOR